# Paypal decode encode issue with + in timestamp

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, decode, encode

I was quite frustrated with IPN testing. Although in the end I was able to pin point the issue in Validate step timestamp field, I need help with how to handle the + sign in time stamp.

I noticed when I decode and encode, the space from Paypal request became + sign. So I did a replacement of + with %20. This was tested okay. However it would be an issue if there is timezone info inside the payment date.

E.g. Fri Jul 08 2016 10:22:01 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)

**parameter came in as:**
            Fri%20Jul%2008%202016%2010%3A22%3A01%20GMT+0800%20%28Malay%20Peninsula%20Standard%20Time%29

**after decoding:**
Fri Jul 08 2016 10:22:01 GMT 0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)    **<=====the plus sign is missing.....**

**encode again:**
Fri+Jul+08+2016+10%3A22%3A01+GMT+0800+%28Malay+Peninsula+Standard+Time%29

What I did was: replay the + sign before decoding with some temp placeholder. then once decode / encode, revert back the replacement.

Some how this could not be verified by Paypal.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it working....not sure whether it's the best way, but works now.

basically I patch the incoming parameter value by replacing + with a placeholder.

```
patchedValue = value.replace("+", "TEMPXXX");

....
```

In the end, after encoding, replace the placeholder with %2B, which is + sign.

```
....
URLEncoder.encode(decodedValue, encoding).replace("+", "%20").replace("TEMPXXX", "%2B")
```